# Hibernate: How to Join three 3 linked tables

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

everyone! Is everything okay with you? I'm stuck with a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for. I have 3 JPA entities:

Entity A:

```java
@Table(name = "A")
@Id
id

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "a_b",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<B> b;
```

Entity B:

```java
@Table(name = "B")
@Id
id

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "b_c",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<C> c;
```

Entity C:

```java
@Table(name = "C")
@Id
id
```

And I have a table to store the 3 keys:

Table a_b_c:

```
ID
idA
idB
idC
```

I need a way to retrieve it like this:

```json
A {
  id: 1
  B {
    id: 1 {
      C {
        id: 1 
        id: 2
      }
    }
    id: 2 {
      C {
        id: 1 
        id: 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the way it is set up, A is only related to B, and B is related to C. I'm not finding a way to connect all 3 so that when I perform a CRUD operation, it retrieves, for example, the A object that has B within it and has the C object related to A and B.

Comment: This is not possible since the Table a_b_c have three fields for three tuples. One A, one B, one C. But your result contains two (or three?) C, not one!

Comment: How so, didnt get